# trying to call function from an external JS file

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i have a very simple asp.net code but my code doesnt make any sense and after run there would be nothing happen .

I'm using external java script file and trying to run my Script from my asp page and in the button object .

Its my asp code :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head ">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Script/Script_Validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" >
<div>
    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="aaaaaa" OnClientClick="valid();"  />
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Its my JS's file content :

```
function valid()
{
    alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
}
```

please help .

Comment: Start by opening the console and checking for errors.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me. Do you definitely have a "Script" folder? Is the name of the file correct? Do you have JavaScript enabled on your browser?

The only problem I can see with your code is your head tag has a single quotation mark ("). Maybe this should be runat="server"?

Comment: Yes im sure about folrder and other things , if i write this script inline or inside my asp page it works but it doesn't work on external JS file !!!

Comment: When debugging your site, if you right click in the browser and choose "View Source", are you able to click the link to "Script/Script_Validate.js" and see the contents of the file?